# What is the advantage of using "Set NOCOUNT ON" in stored procedure's which are used in ssis packages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

While I am going through the performance tuning concepts of SQL Server, I found  stored procedure using `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the initial line and again setting it back to `SET NOCOUNT OFF` on the final line will help to improve performance.

My question here is: how will that be helpful while using the stored procedure with  a SSIS package?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> SET NOCOUNT ON prevents the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages to the client for each statement in a stored procedure. For stored procedures that contain several statements that do not return much actual data, or for procedures that contain Transact-SQL loops, setting SET NOCOUNT to ON can provide a significant performance boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced.

Source BOL: [SET NOCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)

Comment: *Significant* is a bit of a stretch

Comment: @Paparazzi no it isn't. A call that *doesn't* have a return value means there is no reason to use buffers for it or send anything back over the network. Databases are meant to handle many thousands of requests and  small improvements add up

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Eliminate a DONE_IN_PROC is a significant? You need to upgrade your modem.

Comment: @Paparazzi I think you missed the point, or don't grasp that scalability is about latency and roundtrips, not bandwidth. Which is why batching statements is faster than executing individual statements. Perhaps you should check [The Fallacies of Distributed Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing), especially #2 and 7

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to learn?  A stored procedure is a batch and sending a DONE_IN_PROC message is not a round trip.

Comment: @Paparazzi Your point is valid for the majority of cases, however when dealing with procedures that execute statements within loops (yes I know it's bad form) and each statement creates a TCP packet you can't overlook this overhead.

Comment: There are other cases too. Imagine an OLEDB Command destination receiving individual rows. An SSIS package is meant to handle streams of many thousands of rows at a time so the waste adds up. Even if the rows are batched, the server will still send the messages to the client for each row.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Cool and good answer but in today's MB and GB network with available bandwidth you will not see a *significant* performance boost if you put a stopwatch on the stored procedure.   Absolutely use nocount on.

Comment: How SSIS Built internally to handle the difference between messages like "1 row affected" and "actual row"?

Comment: In 2022, is there still a benefit to setting the NO COUNT ON?